# Is there any major difference between thegraph subgrah and openzeppelin subgraph?

Tags: subgraph, openzeppelin, thegraph

As i see, they need similar scheme and manifest to create graphqlients, graph clients is also looks similar. They both can be deployed on thegraph and to the nodes.

There are not so much info about openzeppelin subgraph, and i cant find any comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

OpenZeppelin does not run a blockchain indexing service like TheGraph.

OpenZeppelin does provide [packages](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/subgraphs/0.1.x/) to make it easy to run/ deploy subgraphs that index OpenZeppelin Contracts activity. These subgraphs would be deployed on TheGraph.

I am not sure what you mean by TheGraph subgraph though.

Comment: There are two tools for creating subgrpahs (the things you deploy later on thegrpah service or grpah-node) one is thegraph subgrpah and other is openzepellin subgrpah, they are actually doing the same work, they are very similar in creation, and also giving very similar deploy result, so the question is what the exact difference

Comment: Do you have a link to the "thegraph subgraph"? The link to the OpenZepllelin subgraphs that I provided shows it indexes events related to OpenZepplin contracts. 

TheGraph doesn't produce subgraphs, they provide the underlying technology as you mention.

Comment: The first thing that you see after going to thegraph docs is "How to Use the Subgraph Studio" its literraly what all this docs about. https://thegraph.com/docs/en/deploying/subgraph-studio/